# css: unable to flex-grow when ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, flexbox

i have this code, with 2 examples of flex lists behaving differently although composed from the same items:

[2 examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEbru.png)

```
`<ul class="flex-container">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <li class="flex-item">{{item}}</li>
    </div>
</ul>`


`<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">item1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">item2item2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">item3item3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">item4</li>
</ul>`


`.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;}
.flex-item {
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin:5px;
    font-size:30px;}`
```

is there a way i can  make the first list act like the second, even though it is populated through ng-repeat? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `flex-item` contains `flex-grow: 1;`, and since it's on the the `li`, and the `li` is not a direct child of the flexbox, it's ignored. In addition, `ul` elements direct children should be `li` elements.

Remove the `div` from the 1st list markup, and moved the ngRepeat statement to the `li`:

```
<ul class="flex-container">
     <li class="flex-item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```